# Alt + tab not working ubuntu 19.04 citrix workspace

Tags: shortcut-keys, google-chrome, chromium, 19.04, citrix

I've been searching multiple threads, but can't seem to figure out how to get <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to work on Ubuntu 19.04 with the Citrix Workspace app/extension within Chromium (tried Chrome, too).  There's also an HTML5 in-browser option available that launches my Citrix desktop, but this doesn't allow for <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> either.

Comment: is alt-tab supposed to work when you use it on windows? have you done so? isn't it some other shortcut like `ctrl`+`tab`? have you tried configuring that shortcut in Citrix?

Comment: alt+tab works on windows citrix.  just won't work on ubuntu

Comment: I guess you'll have to unbind alt-tab. in ubuntu keybinds are caught at a system level so if the system already has a binding the OS gets priority if it doesn't you get to have it be caught by whatever application. you can't have a keybinding for a system action and an application. does this answer your question?

Comment: you're amazing....problem solved!  i disable the keyboard shortcut alt + tab in ubuntu and that fixed it (reassigned it to alt + ` ).  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used [tatsu's](https://askubuntu.com/users/307184/tatsu) answer above.  i reassigned the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut to <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> under settings->devices->keyboard->shortcuts.  works like a charm now in chromium :)

Answer (score 0):

Either of these should work

- sudo vim /etc/icaclient/config/All_Regions.ini

  - Set all occurrences of TransparentKeyPassthrough to Remote
- use answer above, disable alt+tab shortcut for your linux. it worked for me