# Alt + Tab Not working in Citrix Receiver 13.10.0.20 in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, citrix

**Things I already tried but not working:**

Many solutions from askubuntu.com have solution like assigning **remote** to **TransparentKeyPassthrough** `/etc/icaclient/config/All_Regions.ini`.
Unfortunatly it is not working for me. :( My current settings are,

```
; These settings control the keyboard settings
;
[Virtual Channels\Keyboard]
TransparentKeyPassthrough=Remote
KeyPassthroughEscapeChar=
```

**Temporary solution**:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1150845/1063899
I currently changed keymapping shortcut in my ubuntu but still Its annoying.

**Version details:**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Citrix Receiver 13.10.0.20